# Usage of 「～に繋げる」

Tags: translation

I am not sure I understand the role of the ～に繋げる【つなげる】 in the following sentence. I feel, that the direct translation as "being connected" is not that good one... So I tried a frivolous  translation:

> 売上【うりあげ】・利益【りえき】の拡大【かくだい】を目指し【めざし】、将来【しょうらい】のための積極的な【せっきょくてきな】投資【とうし】**に繋げる【つなげる】**
>
> Invest actively for the future, by aiming the expansion of sales and
>   profits.

How far am I from the reality and which role does  ～に繋げる【つなげる】 play in this sentence?

Comment: オリジナルのソースに「売上・利益の**拡**大(かくだい)を目指し」ではなく「売上・利益の**広**大(こうだい)を目指し」って書いてあるんですか。

Comment: Oh, my fault, you are right. Thank you for your precious note. Yes, it is 拡大 (かくだい), not 広大 (こうだい).

Comment: Related: [How do 自他 triplets of related verbs work?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12837/78)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are quite close to the intended meaning.

繋げる, while literally meaning

> To connect/tie things together, to anchor

can also have the nuance of

> to continue to something, or to shift (attention/focus/whatever) to something.

So the sentence could be translated as

> Aiming for sales and profit maximization, focus on actively investing for the future.

Reminds me of the phrase 次に繋げる "to lead to the next step".